# time() function to (l jS \of F Y \a\t G:i:s A) format

Tags: php, time

```
function test()
 {
     echo time();
     echo "<hr>";
     echo $this->get_date(time());
}
```

and another function

```
function get_date($timestamp)
{
  $the_date = date('l jS \of F Y \a\t G:i:s A', $timestamp);
  return $the_date;
}
```

when i use the test function the time() function provides a valid result but the generated timestamp is off by 2 hours 
eg. if time() is 1491118740 then the timestamp format should be Sunday 2nd of April 2017 at 7:39:00 AM but i am getting Sunday 2nd of April 2017 at 9:39:00 AM how to fix this?? Please help.. And thanks in advance...
 PS. to check the timestamp value you can use this site http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

Comment: checkout if there time zone differences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update timezone used by your script using `date_default_timezone_set()`

Example:

```
// check your default timezone first
echo date_default_timezone_get();

// change the timezone: I use 'Africa/Lagos' for example
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');

// make sure it's changed
echo date_default_timezone_get();

// now use your function
echo date('l jS \of F Y \a\t G:i:s A');
```

Further reading [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Comment: thanks it seems my default timezone is set to somewhere else instead of UTC